# FirebaseRemoteConfig: Cannot resolve symbol

Tags: android, gradle, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I already use some Firebase packages in my app, today I wanted to implement Remote Configuration. I added it to my app as shown in the [Doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/use-config-android), but something seems to be wrong with my dependencies. Every other Firebase module works, just for remote config it shows

> Cannot resolve symbol 'FirebaseRemoteConfig'

in my activity. I tried re-adding the dependency, multiple gradle syncs, rebuilding the project and restarting the IDE. What could I have done wrong?

Thanks!

EDIT: The problem solved itself: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41664760/3116350

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem. Turns out, I did not include its dependency in gradle:

`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.8.0'`

I assumed it's the same dependency as Firebase Analytics but it's not.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by adding the dependencies with non-BoM.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config-ktx:21.2.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

After about an hour the issue solved itself without me changing anything. Don't know if it was a server-side issue or something else, but it works now.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio, File > Invalidate cache/ restart > Invalidate and Restart.

Solved for me :)